# Repeated Capture Groups in Sed

Tags: linux, sed

I've a pattern like this:

```
#ABC: (0),(0-11,22),(A7E2BB0F38DF),(42),(1A0290800D7),(7042),(81A0290800D7),(7442)
```

I want to following result using sed:

```
0 0-11,22 A7E2BB0F38DF 42 1A0290800D7 7042 81A0290800D7 7442
```

Following works in bash:

```bash
result="#ABC: (0),(0-11,22),(A7E2BB0F38DF),(42),(1A0290800D7),(7042),(81A0290800D7),(7442)"
sed -n 's/.*(\(.*\)),(\(.*\)),(\(.*\)),(\(.*\)),(\(.*\)),(\(.*\)),(\(.*\)),(\(.*\))/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8/p' <<< "$result"
```

```
0 0-11,22 A7E2BB0F38DF 42 1A0290800D7 7042 81A0290800D7 7442
```

Now, how do I optimize this sed expression? How to remove the redundant capture groups?

Answer (score 3):

Would this do?

```
% sed -Ee 's/[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)/\1 /g' < input.txt
0 0-11,22 A7E2BB0F38DF 42 1A0290800D7 7042 81A0290800D7 7442
```

That is, match anything up to the first open parenthesis (`[^(]*\(`), then capture anything that isn't a closing one (`([^)]*)`), then match the closing parenthesis, replace the lot with the captured part (`\1`) and do the same thing again for the rest of the string (`/g`).

Or in Perl:

```
% perl -ne 'print "$1 " while(/\((.*?)\)/g); print "\n"' < input.txt
0 0-11,22 A7E2BB0F38DF 42 1A0290800D7 7042 81A0290800D7 7442
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the original input shown in the question is not a fragment of a larger document in some structured document format like YAML or JSON.  If it were, there may be better ways to achieve this than what is presented here or in other answers.

---

This achieves what you want to do in the opposite way from what you specify it.  Instead of trying to match and keep what's within the parentheses, this removes the first `(` and everything before it, the last `)` and everything after it, and then replace each instance of the `),(` substring with a space:

```bash
$ sed -e 's/[^(]*(//' -e 's/)[^)]*$//' -e 's/),(/ /g' file
0 0-11,22 A7E2BB0F38DF 42 1A0290800D7 7042 81A0290800D7 7442
```

Or, doing the replacement of `),(` with spaces first, which allows us to rewrite the other substitutions without the need for quite so many brackets and parentheses (assuming none of the outer parentheses in the input contains parenthesized substrings):

```bash
$ sed -e 's/),(/ /g' -e 's/.*(//' -e 's/).*//' file
0 0-11,22 A7E2BB0F38DF 42 1A0290800D7 7042 81A0290800D7 7442
```

What's left are the substrings not outside of a parenthesis (space-delimited).

---

A totally different approach is to convert the input to properly quoted CSV by stripping off the text in front of the first `(`, then translating each `(` and `)` into double quotes.  We may then use `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to change the default field delimiter to space:

```bash
$ sed -e 's/[^(]*(/(/' -e 'y/()/""/' file | csvformat -D ' '
0 0-11,22 A7E2BB0F38DF 42 1A0290800D7 7042 81A0290800D7 7442
```